# Time difference while storing avro messages to hdfs directory using kafka connect hdfs sink connector

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to find the latency of the hdfs sink connector. I have overall 14 00 000 messages
I triggered the curl command to create hdfs sink connector with flush size as 2 00 000.
During the first time it took almost 11 minutes to complete the task.
After checking logs i got to know that i had other connectors running , So in the next round of testing I deleted all other connectors and deleted the hdfs directory, log directory, +tmp directory.
I deleted the previous connector as well and ran the curl command with new connector name and flush size set to same 2 00 000 messages. This time within 20 seconds all the messages were in the hdfs directory. Could someone please explain why there is such strange time gap for processing . first time it took around 11 minutes for the same topic and in the next test it processed within 20 seconds

Connector properties:
{"name":"RetestPerf_2","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector","flush.size":"200000","tasks.max":"15","topics":"RetestPerf","hdfs.url":"hdfs://hostname:8020/topics","name":"RetestPerf_2"},"tasks":[{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":0},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":1},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":2},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":3},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":4},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":5},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":6},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":7},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":8},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":9},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":10},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":11},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":12},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":13},{"connector":"RetestPerf_2","task":14}]}[

Comment: Please add your Connect properties to the question

Comment: Hi , I have edited and added my connector properties

Comment: Alright, 15 tasks is a lot when according to the question you're only need 7. And you're using all the default partitioner properties? The second time you start Connect, the consumer group was already caught up... Just because you deleted hdfs files doesn't mean it'll restart from the beginning